# Который или которая?

Tags: склонение, спп

Шар Древесного Духа был единственной драгоценной вещью, который принадлежал только древесному духу.

Или нужно написать:

Шар Древесного Духа был единственной драгоценной вещью, которая принадлежала только древесному духу.

Немного затупил и не пойму.

Comment: Которая, которая.

Answer (score 2):

При таком порядке слов придаточное предложение относится к слову *вещь*: вещь (какая?), **которая** **принадлежала** только древесному духу.

Можно изменить порядок слов так, чтобы придаточное предложение относилось к слову *шар* и  отвечало на вопрос *какой?*. Например так.

Шар Древесного Духа, **который** **принадлежал** только древесному духу, был единственной драгоценной вещью (в этом лесу).